# Why CSS Floats Don't Work When I Need Them To

Tags: css, css-float, multiple-columns

I was making a grid of blocks, sort of like a Pinterest layout, when I discovered that floated elements all expand to the height of the tallest block in their row.

"Hey!" I thought. "How about applying this to make my sidebar the same height as my content!" But for some reason it doesn't work that way. I looked all over to find a solution for equal-height columns that just uses floats as if they were a grid, but there doesn't seem to be one.

So my question could be summed up as this: How do you make equal-height columns as easily as the grid of floating squares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can do equal-height columns -- without hacks, JavaScript, or a million extra bits of mark-up (though support isn't great in IE7 or lower).  The secret is using `display: table-cell` on adjacent elements.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="col1">
        Small content here
    </div>

    <div id="col2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.container { display: table }

div.container > div { display: table-cell; border: 1px solid; padding: 1em }

div#col1 { background: orange }
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/y9e4d/

Answer (score 1):

You can use height: 100%, but that requires parent element to have 100% height.
Start by setting html and body height to 100% and work your way down through the elements.

You can also use jQuery to get the height of a specific element, and then set the height of your sidebar using jQuery, based on the selected element.

Could be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#sidebar').height($('#container').height());
});
```

Working example:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
                         $('#sidebar').height($('#container').height());
                    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

            <div style="height: 200px; border: 1px solid red; width: 500px; float: left;" id="container">Content</div>
            <div style="border: 1px solid green;" id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```